# Java multi-dimensional array is not populating correctly

Tags: java, arrays

I have declared a multi- dimensional array like this:

```
String[][] contentDetails  = {};
```

I populated the array like this:

```
contentDetails[][]  = {{"Availability","Available from: "+empst}, 
                     {"Rate in EUR/Hour",rst.getString(25)}};
```

It is getting error. How can I do that? I am new this. Please help me.

What I want is an empty array first and then need to populate!!

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan error ";" expected

Comment: Show tha whole traceback please.

Comment: If you want the array to be empty at first, you have to give it an initial size. Arrays can't be resized in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because array constants can only be used in initializers.

The following would work:

```
 String[][] contentDetails  = {{"Availability","Available from: "+empst}, 
                                {"Rate in EUR/Hour", rst.getString(25)}};
```

If you don't want to fill it on instantiation you need to instantiate the array giving it the length for both dimensions like this:

String[][] contentDetails = new String [length1][length2];

where **length1** and **length2** are integers (int).

Comment: I need to be array first empty then only i am populating with if and else conditions.

Comment: @androidGenX Then you need to instantiate it when you declare it. Like this: String[][] contentDetails = new String [size1][size2]. After this you can fill it with your strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use *Arrays constant* when creating the array, not after. It make sense because, how Java would know the size of the array when instantiating otherwise ?

So you can do this

```
String[][] contentDetails = {{"Availability","Available from: "+empst}, 
            {"Rate in EUR/Hour",rst.getString(25)}};
```

or declare the array then loop over it to set the values

```
String[][] contentDetails [2][2];

...

for(int i = 0;i<2;i++)
  for(int j = 0;j<2;j++)
    //set the value of contentDetails here
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in Java looks like this:

```
String[][] contentDetails = new String[][] {
    new String[] { "Availability", "Available from: "+empst }, 
    new String[] { "Rate in EUR/Hour", rst.getString(25) }
};
```